# Grab data in excel from an excel that will be downloaded tomorrow

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have set up a way to automatically download my Google webmaster tool data every day. Now, I have a main excel sheet which holds all that data, that I normally update manually. However, I'd like to be able update data from the downloaded files automatically. I know it's possible to grab data from other existing excel files, but since the file names change after each download I'm not sure how to go about it for this application. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: More information is needed. How is the data downloaded; is it an export into excel or a file you download? How or why do the file names change? How do you manually update your file? Is there a reason you can not import the data directly into your Excel file?

Comment: I'm importing wmt data using Python. www.seo.com/blog/tutorial-google-webmaster-tools-data-windows-python/ 

Then I'm going to use cron to run that script daily. 

I want to pull impressions and clicks from those daily reports, to auto update on my master excel file. 

The file names are not predicable because the "151543Z" changes on each download: www-client-com_20140325T151543Z_TopSearchQueries_20140223-20140325

I can't import the data directly into the excel file because I'm not familiar enough with the web master tools API, it could be possible, but I haven't heard anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since there aren't many particulars in your post, here's a broadly defined option you could choose. You can get around the changing-reference problem by **first passing the new data into a database**. Then, your master workbook can query the database rather than the downloaded file.

You seem to know enough programming that this shouldn't be too horribly difficult to implement. Roughly, you would schedule a bulk insert task to follow the new file being downloaded. Microsoft Access would be sufficient for this task and easy to query from Excel. Otherwise a lightweight DB like SQLite3 would suffice, but you may run into difficulty querying from Excel (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1630035/657668) for more detail).

Comment: Thanks, excelll. However, I think you've given my programming skills too much credit. I'm a great at searching for tutorials on Google lol. This is something I don't mind looking up to figure out, but I have no idea where to start. To clarify, what is a bulk insert task? I have very limited SQL knowledge...

Comment: You should be able to Google most of the SQL and Python you need to do this. Just choose a database to use (e.g., Access, MSSQL Server, SQLite3) then set up a table in the database that matches the fields and formats of the downloaded data. This step can be WYSIWYG in Access and SQL Server. Then Google "python insert CSV microsoft access" or whatever to find which python library you should use and how to set up your code. Feel free to check back here or on Stack Overflow if you run into problems.